# alias with 2 commands does not get input parameter

Tags: linux, shell

under Ubuntu 18 Linux I try to set an alias in .bash_aliases
with 2 commands in it, and reading an input parameter

```
alias nd="mkdir $1 && cd $1"
```

I do "nd qq", and the result is

```
mkdir: missing operand
```

Where is my error ? 
Any help is welcome

PD.- I have an alias with "parameter" that works fine :

```
alias mira="ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $1"
```

I do "mira dhcp" and result is OK

PD2.- if I code

```
alias nd="mkdir $1"
```

... it works perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running `alias nd` afterward? The output is

```
alias nd='mkdir  && cd '
```

which should let you see that something has gone wrong.

When you feed the shell with

```
alias nd="mkdir $1 && cd $1"
```

the processes this line; among other things, the processing results in expanding the variable `$1`, which is empty in your current environment, as you can see by entering `echo $1` in the terminal.

Bottom line: `alias` is not the tool for this. A function is the tool for this. Run the following in your shell, and then `nd` will do what you want.

```
nd() { mkdir $1 && cd $1; }
```

When you do

```
alias nd="mkdir $1"
```

this explands to

```
alias nd='mkdir '
```

(the trailing space really does nothing) so you have just created another name for `mkdir`, much like you had done

```
alias nd=mkdir
```

and this is why it "works".